# Перенос сайта с хостинга, на локальный сервер CMS Modx

Tags: modx, веб-сервер, denwer, cms

Возникла проблема при переносе сайта с сервера на локальный сервер. Панель администартора доступна, все работает, а сам сайт при просмотре пустой экран выдает, пыталась сбросить кэш не помогло? затем проверяла пути их также правила на нужные. В чем возможная причина?

Comment: так же настроен а htaccess стандартный от modx

Comment: на хостинге создавалось виртуальное окружение

Comment: проверить пути к конфигам можно.

Comment: проверяла, просто я не пойму почему админка сайта работает и полностью все показывает, все документы записи, а сам сайт ничего не отображает...

Comment: ведь по логике, если пути были бы указаны не правильно, то тогда я бы и не смогла зайти в админку.

Comment: >ведь по логике, если пути были бы указаны не правильно, то тогда я бы и не смогла зайти в админку.

нет не правильно.

Пути могут отличаться. я, к сожалению год назад работал с ModX и сейчас точно не подскажу.

Comment: MODx при установке вписывает в базу отдельно пути для сайта. В двух таблицах эти пути нужно заменить на новые соответственно и будет Вам счастье.
А админка работает при переносе без проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Админка modx'a работает по относительным путям. Пути рабочие можно поправить через саму админку в закладке "Конфигурация".

Попробуйте сохранить любой ресурс (документ) в админке.
Если вас пошлет - проставите права 0777 на папку /assets/cache/ и всё её содержимое.

Переименуйте файл .htaccess (и попробуйте перед этим закоментировать (#) опцию *Options +FollowSymlinks* - нарывались).

Если не помогло - попробуйте посмотреть логи апача - возможно где-то идет креш РНР (есть хостинги, где не выдается текст критической ошибки в РНР), возможно на самописных кусках, возможно из-за смены версии РНР. Попробуйте сделать и высести чистый шаблон *(blank)* с текстом типа *"123"* - если отработало - значит изучаем снипеты - может им чего-то не хватает (прав, модулей).

Как самый крайний резервный вариант - переустановка CMS с последующим залитием БД и контента поверху.